# Compactification of $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

I would like to prove that
$$ X = X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3 \subseteq \mathbb R^2, $$
where
$$ X_1 = \{0\} \times[-1,1], $$
$$ X_2 = \{(x,\sin(1/x)):0 < x  \leq 2/3\pi\} $$
and $X_3$ is an arc with endpoints $(0,-1)$ and $(2/3\pi, -1)$ with disjoint interior of $X_1\cup X_2$ is a compactification of $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology. I've thinked in kind of stereographic projection of $X_1$ and $X_3$ and an interval $[a,\infty)$, but I would appreciate some ideas and hints to formalize this reasoning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sets $X_i$ are trivially subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and hence so too is their union. Unless I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: @par I would like to prove that $X$ is a compactification of $\mathbb R$, so I need to prove there exists a continuous map $h: \mathbb R \to X$ with $h(\mathbb R)$ dense in $X$.

Comment: Ah. You should write that in the question body.

Comment: @par I wrote it

Comment: It's vaguely present in the title, but your question body just says "I would like to prove $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$."

Comment: @par: It’s in the body: *I would like to prove that ... is a compactification of* $\Bbb R$ *with the usual topology*.

Comment: Fair enough. It was a bit hard to parse.

Comment: @AlbertT.: haven't you got $X$ and $\mathbb{R}$ the wrong way round in your first comment? Don't you want a continuous map $h : \mathbb{R} \to X$ with $h(\mathbb{R})$ dense in $X$? I expect you probably want $h$ to be $1$-$1$ too.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, but I can't correct it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Since $\Bbb R$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^+$, the set of positive reals, it suffices to show that $X$ is a compactification of $\Bbb R^+$. Map $(0,1]$ to $X_3\setminus\{\langle 0,-1\rangle\}$ and $[1,\to)$ to $X_2$ in the most natural way. Show that the resulting map is a homeomorphism. Intuitively, think of $\Bbb R^+$ as a string that you’re laying out starting at (but not including) $\langle 0,-1\rangle$, running across $X_3$, and then back to the left along $X_2$.

Comment: @Albert: See the corrected version. $X_1$ is actually the remainder of the compactification.

Comment: Great, $X_1$ needs not to be mapped by it because the image of $\mathbb R^+$ is already dense, right?

Comment: @Albert: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: @Rob: Thanks! $\,$